# Remove File From GIT Commit and Keep Changes

Tags: git, file, commit

I've been trying to push these 4 commits only to see it's not possible due to the size of one of the files (a PDF). I have installed git LFS and added tracking for that large file (gut LFS tracking *.pdf) but I still get the same error.

I have tried looking for how to remove the file from the commits, but can't find anything clear and concise. I don't want to reset to head and then lose my commits if I've done it wrong.

Any pointers or information on either of these two options (using LFS correctly, and removing the file from all four commits) would be appreciated.

```
Enumerating objects: 863, done.
Counting objects: 100% (863/863), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (758/758), done.
Writing objects: 100% (834/834), 245.10 MiB | 2.91 MiB/s, done.
Total 834 (delta 111), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (111/111), completed with 7 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 3c5c28a3d91ced
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File TI - Code/simplelink_msp432p4_sdk_3_40_01_02.run is 214.80 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/YYYYY/Autonomous-Craft-2D.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/YYYYY/Autonomous-Craft-2D.git'
```

I do know variations of this have been asked before, but I have 4 commits with the same file, and I need to go back not just one or two commits, I need to go through them all without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the File from All Commits:

**( Make sure to have a backup in case something messes up )**

Use interactive rebase:

1. Run below command to start an interactive rebase, editing the last 4 commits.

> git rebase -i HEAD~4

2. Change `pick` to `edit` for each commit containing the file.
3. For each edited commit:

> git ls-files --cached (to see cached files and there paths)
>
> git rm --cached "path/to/file"
>
> git commit --amend (use proper commit message such as "removed file x")

4. Continue the rebase with:

> git rebase --continue.

Comment: Do you mean in Step 1  I would use ~4 then ~3... as I work through the last 4 commits? Also can you please clarify in step 2 where I am changing "pick" to "edit". Thank you

Comment: [All use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT and other LLMs) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) when posting content on Stack Overflow. This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.

Comment: No you do not have to do it step wise; you can change all the four commits in a single rebase. For step 2, I hope you have a global editor set such as vim. If not use : git config --global core.editor "vim". It is too long to explain all this in comment so I made a complete guide for you along with a Readme file , you can just follow the readme file . here is the link to my google drive : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1h1QB1QmrzYJO7gTpB--hA9p7qnB93kOf?usp=drive_link

Comment: You can post your response here as a response, and not as a comment...